# Creating a link by cell information in row in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code I'm working with, to make it Mac/PC complaint with help from here, but after this is done running on my PC at least for now, I have created a folder with a company name, and part number folder for later use.

```
Sub MakeFolder()

Dim strComp As String, strPart As String, strPath As String

strComp = Range("A1") ' assumes company name in A1
strPart = CleanName(Range("C1")) ' assumes part in C1
strPath = "C:\Images\"

If Not FolderExists(strPath & strComp) Then 
'company doesn't exist, so create full path
    FolderCreate strPath & strComp & "\" & strPart
Else
'company does exist, but does part folder
    If Not FolderExists(strPath & strComp & "\" & strPart) Then
        FolderCreate strPath & strComp & "\" & strPart
    End If
End If

End Sub

Function FolderCreate(ByVal path As String) As Boolean

FolderCreate = True
Dim fso As New FileSystemObject

If Functions.FolderExists(path) Then
    Exit Function
Else
    On Error GoTo DeadInTheWater
    fso.CreateFolder path 
    Exit Function
End If

DeadInTheWater:
    MsgBox "A folder could not be created for the following path: " & path & ". Check the path name and try again."
    FolderCreate = False
    Exit Function

End Function

Function FolderExists(ByVal path As String) As Boolean

FolderExists = False
Dim fso As New FileSystemObject

If fso.FolderExists(path) Then FolderExists = True

End Function

Function CleanName(strName as String) as String
'will clean part # name so it can be made into valid folder name
'may need to add more lines to get rid of other characters

    CleanName = Replace(strName, "/","")
    CleanName = Replace(CleanName, "-","")
    etc...

End Function
```

Now what I am attempting to do is make it so that if said Customer exists, and SO# Folder Exists, to create a link to it in P. on the same row.

Now as shown below the path is C:\Images\Company Name\SO#\

The link I'd like to have would say in the representing row would be Pictures for "SO#" the SO# would be replaced with the SO# of the row itself. Then when you click on it, the link brings you to the folder in Explorer.

Theoretically I could make it so that the code looks like this, but I'm not sure entirely...

```
Option Explicit

Sub Create_a_Link()

    Dim wsJAR As Worksheet 'JL Archive
    Dim lastrow As Long, fstcell As Long
    Set wsJAR = Sheets("JL Archive")

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .DisplayAlerts = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

     With JAR
        lastrow = wsJAR.Cells(Rows.Count, "P").End(xlUp).Row
        Range("P3:P" & lastrow).Value = Hyperlink("C:\$C3:C" & lastrow \" & "B3:B" & lastrow, "Cellname")
    End With

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .DisplayAlerts = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With
```

but I keep getting an error here:

```
   Range("P3:P" & lastrow).Value = Hyperlink("C:\$C3:C" & lastrow \" & "B3:B" & lastrow, "Cellname")
```

Says a compile error: Expected list separator or )

If anyone can help it be appreciated...Attached is the excel sheet.

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/3327208/Excel/picture.xlsx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you don't have the right syntax to create a hyperlink. I used the macro recorder to see the code to add a hyperlink to a sheet. I also googled "Excel VBA add hyperlink to range". The resulting sytax is below:

```
ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=myRange, Address:= myPath, TextToDisplay:= myText

myRange = the place you want the hyperlink to go
myPath = the path of the hyperlink
myText = the text you want to display
```

Here I gave you your answer, but also, how to best go about finding your own answer in the future. Learning how to search for answers is half the battle of learning how to code in VBA!

** EDIT **

Also, you can't set the whole range at once. You have to loop through rows and add each hyperlink separately. Otherwise, you can add the hyperlink when you create the job (take from past convos.)

Comment: Thanks, and I have been goggling for the past few hours for answers. I've come up with several, but the problem comes for me that I need to expand greatly on what you are saying. I may make it so that it's a cell reference... which is what I was trying to do originally, but thought VBA may be the way to go.

Comment: Not 100% sure what you mean, but make it a cell reference, but hyperlinks can point to any place within your document, within a drive, a website, and maybe to anyplace in another document as well - will have to check on that. Also, I remember when I was in your shoes...  googling code help is the art of learning how to ask the question!

Comment: This is what I've come up with. I decided to use `=INFO("SYSTEM")` in a cell on a hidden page. With that, in the cell I want to have the link I did this: `=HYPERLINK(Lists!$G$2  & $C$3 & "\" & $B$3 & "\", $B$3 & " Photos")` the problem I have now is that in B3 it shows `35166 R01/02`. I need to make it so that it replaces `/` with `*`. Do you have any idea of how to make this happen?

Comment: Ah, I see what you are doing now with the hyperlink. This is really a new question, but since it's simple enough, just wrap a substitute function around the $B$3 reference. so substitute($B$3,"/","*")

Comment: I know it's a new question, but I decided to take another route since writing a script to do it would be a little more complex than I cared to imagine right now... thanks though. this is what I came up with. `=HYPERLINK(Lists!$G$2  & $C$3 & "\" & SUBSTITUTE($B3,"/","*") & "\", SUBSTITUTE($B3,"/","*") & " Photos")`